# Antlr parser ambiguous literal

Tags: antlr

I have a grammar like this:

```
grammar a;
rule : cccc direction;
cccc: Char Char Char Char;
direction: Digit Digit Digit 'V' Digit Digit Digit;

Char : [A-Z];
Digit: [0-9];
WS: [ \t\n\r=] ->skip;
```

I want parser String "AVBC 120V230" ,but i got tips:

```
line 1:1 extraneous input 'V' expecting Char
line 1:5 missing Char at '1'
```

what should  I do ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a literal token inside a parser rule (`'V'` in your case), ANTLR treats the complete grammar like this:

```
grammar a;
rule : cccc direction;
cccc: Char Char Char Char;
direction: Digit Digit Digit T__0 Digit Digit Digit;

T__0 : 'V';
Char : [A-Z];
Digit: [0-9];
WS: [ \t\n\r] ->skip; // you included the `=` here: I assumed it was a typo
```

And ANTLR will always create a `T__0` for the input `V`. This means `V` will never be tokenized as a `Char` token. If you want `V` to also become a `Char`, you'll need to move this in a parser rule:

```
grammar a;
rule : cccc direction;
cccc: ch ch ch ch;
direction: Digit Digit Digit V Digit Digit Digit;
ch : V | Char;

V : 'V';
Char : [A-Z];
Digit: [0-9];
WS: [ \t\n\r] ->skip;
```

and your input `AVBC 120V230` is properly parsed:

[image]

Note that I don't know how your language looks like, but letting the lexer tokenize just single bytes/chars and gluing them together in parser rules seems a bit odd. While this is possible, in ANTLR you generally define tokens with a bit more substance. From your example, I'd say defining an `Identifier` and `Direction` token more appropriate:

```
rule : cccc direction;
cccc: Identifier;
direction: Direction;

Identifier : [A-Z]+;
Direction : [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] 'V' [0-9] [0-9] [0-9];
WS: [ \t\n\r] ->skip;
```

Comment: thanks,bart! i am new one for antlr, I try parse WMO（wmo.int） message using antlr，message like this:
"
METAR
LOWG 010720Z 03003KT 330V060 0200 R16/0225N R34/0500N FG VV001
01/01 Q1008 BECMG TL0800 0600 FG VV002 BECMG FM0800 1200 BCFG
BKN003=
"
can I do this using antlr? can you give me some advice?

Comment: You're welcome @laowang. I'm not familiar with WMO messages, so I cannot comment on the fact ANTLR is a suitable tool, or something else would be. Note that the way you've started (creating single char/byte tokens in lexer rules) is perhaps not usually done with ANTLR, but it is possible.

Comment: Thanks,bart! I understand your mean,and change my g4 rule ,but some ambiguous literal trouble me. thank you again. i will try more